# Javascript callback function error

Tags: javascript, express, callback

For some reason the code I wrote below(an POST route I was making) is not exactly working how I thought it would.

```
app.post("/", function (req, res, error) {
  var message = "";
  tableSvc.createTable("tableName", function (error, result,response){
      if (error) 
        message += "There was an error in creating this table";
      else 
        message += "Table created succesfully";

  }); 
  console.log(message);     
});
```

Instead of printing `"There was an error..."` or `"Table created..."`, the code above only prints out an empty string.
I know that the call-back function is being executed because if I put `console.log(message)` inside of the call-back function, then either of the above two strings does get printed to the console.
I am new to Javascript and call-functions, so why isn't my code executing the way I intended it to?

Comment: The `createTable` call is asynchronous, so when you console.log the message, the callback hasn't executed yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the scope of variable message is the problem here. I have not tried this but may work.

```
 app.post("/", function (req, res, error) {
    var obj = this;
    obj.message = '';
      tableSvc.createTable("tableName", function (error, result,response){
          if (error) 
            obj.message += "There was an error in creating this table";
          else 
            obj.message += "Table created succesfully";

      }); 

      while(obj.message.length===0){
            ;//Block the next execution till the operation above is complete.
      }


      console.log(obj.message);     
    });
```

Comment: And I think, as tableSvc.createTable is asynchronous, this may execute console.log(obj.message) before it actually completes the callback function. You should either move the logic in callback function itself. or make the call synchronously. or use setInterval later unless the variable (message) value is changed by callback.

Comment: Yeah, if that method is asynchronous then it also explains other behavior I have noticed with it.  Accepted answer(more for your comment than answer:)

Comment: I understood 2/3 solutions, but how could I make the call synchronously without changing the actual method itself?

Comment: I am not sure, which library are you using for "tableSvc.createTable" . I just pointed the hint, there are few async functions which have config parameters like we have for jQuery.ajax() function, we can configure async:false to make that call synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Removed my guess - missed your point about the callback being executed - it's likely the asynch problem offered by the other reply.